# Designing an interface between C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have code for a physics simulation in C++. I am trying to solve a control problem using Deep Reinforcement Learning. Most of the popular packages such as keras, pytorch, are based on Python. So, my machine learning code resides in Python and the physics simulator code is in C++.

At every iteration of the machine learning algorithm, I require a call to the C++ program and want the program to persist its state (maintain the variable values). One way I came up with was reading and writing variable values to files. But this didn't seem scalable considering the high number of variables in the program. I googled and found Boost Python library for wrapping my entire C++ code, so that it might be available to the Python program. My question is by doing this do I lose all the speed up of running the code in C++?

Also, I came across numba, which according to the creators is specifically designed for speed up for Scientific Computing and can reach speeds as fast as native C++. But, this would essentially mean re-writing the entire code in Python. Will this be a better choice?

I am on a strict timeline for my project and any advice on which way I should go will be much appreciated.

Comment: To quickly interface an existing code with Python, I recommend [SWIG](http://swig.org/).  There is also a short tutorial on their website: http://swig.org/tutorial.html

Comment: @HenriMenke I will check that out. But what about the speed? Is it as fast as native C++?

Comment: The speed of the C++ code is not affected by the wrapping.  Only the speed of calling the C++ code changes.  In your case, it might even be faster because you don't have to spawn a shell anymore.

Comment: I checked the tutorial on the SWIG website. It essentially does the same thing as boost Python. We create a dynamic library and make it visible to Python. I am still confused about the speed though. Let's suppose we have some code in C++ and run some computations in that. Now, I wrap that code for Python. When I use it in Python, wouldn't the computations be done by Python and slow compared to C++?

Comment: The C++ code will remain untouched (and therefore maintains its performance).  You only *add* an interface to it.  The Boost.Python approach works similar to SWIG, but requires you to write a lot more code.

Comment: In general, write the code and get a working solution.  If it is not fast enough, optimize. It will usually be fast enough.  Many python developers and c++ developers use python to create an accurate algorithm, and later optimize those parts which involve the lion share of the looping and processing.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for the advice. You are absolutely correct. I am already done implementing the wrapper for my C++ code. Never thought it would be this easy. I experimented with PyBindGen, but the lack of good documentation was very frustrating. With SWIG, I just had to setup a basic environment and then I sequentially kept adding code to the module. It was super simple like you said.